# PowerShell Script Directory List At A Depth And Provide Size

Tags: powershell

My folder structure is:

```
P:\12345
P:\12345\001
P:\12345\001\folder
P:\12345\002
P:\12345\002\folder
P:\67890
P:\67890\001
P:\67890\002
```

etc

my end goal is to create a single script that will provide me a csv with the path to the second level and provide the size at this level and below. I currently have this working in two different scripts.

Output:

```
P:\12345\001; 1003
P:\12345\002; 631
P:\67890\001; 594
P:\67890\002; 467
```

Can this be done is a single script?

```
$startFolder = "P:\01520"
$output = "c:\temp\01520.csv"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
$results = @()
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $i.FullName
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $results += '"' +$i.FullName + '"' + ";" + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB)
    }
$results > $output
```

============================

```
Get-ChildItem \*\* | % { if ($_.Attributes -eq "Directory") { Out-File C:\Temp\DirList.txt -append -inputobject $_.FullName } }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do that. it builds a `[PSCustomObject]` that has the data from the various dir trees and outputs that to a `$Results` collection that is shown on screen and saved to a CSV file.

```
# fake reading in a list of dirs
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$DirList = @'
C:\Temp\Logitech
C:\Temp\BackupSets - Copy
C:\Temp\chocolatey
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($DL_Item in $DirList)
    {
    $SubDirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $DL_Item -Directory
    foreach ($SDL_Item in $SubDirList)
        {
        $DirTreeInfo = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SDL_Item.FullName -Recurse -File
        $Size_MB = [math]::Round(($DirTreeInfo |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB, 2)
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DirName = $SDL_Item.FullName
            FileCount = $DirTreeInfo.Count
            Size_MB = $Size_MB
            }
        }
    }

# on screen
$Results

# send to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\TomMaleski_-_DirTreeSizeList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

truncated output to screen ...

```
DirName                                     FileCount Size_MB
-------                                     --------- -------
C:\Temp\Logitech\Logitech_Gaming_Software_1       126    1.09
C:\Temp\BackupSets - Copy\2019-05-19                2       0
C:\Temp\BackupSets - Copy\2019-05-20                2       0
C:\Temp\chocolatey\ConEmu                           1    6.85

[*...snip...*] 

C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\test 4.poiu                      0       0
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff                    40   66.16
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff - Copy             40   66.16
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users                           35   66.16
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy                    35   66.16
```

truncated CSV file content ...

```
"DirName","FileCount","Size_MB"
"C:\Temp\Logitech\Logitech_Gaming_Software_1","126","1.09"
"C:\Temp\BackupSets - Copy\2019-05-19","2","0"
"C:\Temp\BackupSets - Copy\2019-05-20","2","0"
"C:\Temp\chocolatey\ConEmu","1","6.85"

[*...snip...*] 

"C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\test 4.poiu","0","0"
"C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff","40","66.16"
"C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff - Copy","40","66.16"
"C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users","35","66.16"
"C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy","35","66.16"
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner with aliases:

```
gci P:\*\* -Directory | %{"{0}; {1}" -f $_.FullName,(gci $_ -File -Recurse|measure Length -sum).Sum}
```

Sample output of my `Q:\Test\*` folder

```
Q:\Test\2015; 14977618
Q:\Test\2016; 6847244
Q:\Test\2017; 40056457
Q:\Test\2018; 405594085
Q:\Test\2019; 1551213
```

Answer (score 0):

Using many examples, i had to write my own solution to list directories and sizes in a deep level. Is a recursive solutions that uses all childs iterations to sum, avoiting repeat sum files size again (more eficient).

```
powershell -command ".\scriptMida.ps1 -Directory c:\hp -level 2 -HiddeErrors"

Temps#nivell#DirectoryPath#FileSize#FileSize(MB)#FileSize(GB)
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\BIN#347095#0.33#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\bridge#2460#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\bridge#2460#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\browser#78553#0.07#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\BTBHost#715797#0.68#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Favs#6098#0.01#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Netflix#76#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Simplesolitaire#6#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\HPQWare#803076#0.77#0.00
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\McAfeeRules#8014#0.01#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\support\flexroot#152866#0.15#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\support#320415#0.31#0.00
```

The code is in github https://github.com/elmeuavi/RecursiveDirSize with examples and with also another "human" presentation and with a secondary script to compare 2 executions of same directories.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).